# Database in Excel using win32com or xlrd Or Database in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, excel, win32com, xlrd

I have developed a website where the pages are simply html tables.  I have also developed a server by expanding on python's `SimpleHTTPServer`.  Now I am developing my database.

Most of the table contents on each page are static and doesn't need to be touched.  However, there is one column per table (i.e. page) that needs to be editable and stored.  The values are simply text that the user can enter. The user enters the text via `html textareas` that are appended to the tables via javascript.

The database is to store key/value pairs where the value is the user entered text (for now at least).

**Current situation**

Because the original format of my webpages was `xlsx` files I opted to use an excel workbook as my database that basically just mirrors the displayed web html tables (pages).

I hook up to the excel workbook through `win32com`.  Every time the table (page) loads, `javascript` iterates through the html textareas and sends an individual request to the server to load in its respective text from the database.

Currently this approach works but is terribly slow.  I have tried to optimize everything as much as I can and I believe the speed limitation is a direct consequence of `win32com`.

Thus, I see four possible ways to go:

1. Replace my current `win32com` functionality with `xlrd`
2. Try to load all the html textareas for a table (page) at once through one server call to the database using `win32com`
3. Switch to something like `sql` (probably use mysql since it's simple and robust enough for my needs)
4. Use `xlrd` but make a single call to the server for each table (page) as in (2)

My schedule to build this functionality is around two days.

Does anyone have any thoughts on the tradeoffs in time-spent-coding versus speed of these approaches?  If anyone has any better/more streamlined methods in mind please share!

Comment: Excel is not a database. Don't use it like that. Your future self will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but your post is very broad, and I've used win32coma and Excel a fair but and don't see those as good tools towards your goal. An easier strategy is this:

- for the server, use **Flask**: it is a Python HTTP server that makes it crazy easy to respond to HTTP requests via Python code and HTML templates. You'll have a fully capable server running in 5 minutes, then you will need a bit of time create code to get data from your DB and render from templates (which are really easy to use).
- for the database, use **SQLite** (there is far more overhead intergrating with MysQL); because you only have 2 days, so

  - you could also use a simple **CSV** file, since the API (Python has a CSV file read/write module) is much simpler, less ramp up time. One CSV per user, easy to manage. You don't worry about insertion of rows for a user, you just append; and you don't implement remove of rows for a user, you just mark as inactive (a column for active/inactive in your CSV). In processing GET request from client, as you read from the CSV, you can count how many certain rows are inactive, and do a re-write of the CSV, so once in a while the request will be a little slower to respond to client.
  - even simpler yet you could use **in-memory data structure** of your choice if you don't need persistence across restarts of the *server*. If this is for a demo this should be acceptable limitation.
- for the client side, use **jQuery** on top of javascript -- maybe you are doing that already. Makes it super easy to manipulate the DOM and use effects like slide-in/out etc. Get yourself the book "Learning jQuery", you'll be able to make good use of jQuery in just a couple hours.

If you only have two days it might be a little tight, but you will probably need more than 2 days to get around the issues you are facing with your current strategy, and issues you will face imminently.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm doing the client side as you said already so that is great.

Comment: As far as the server goes, is there a noticeable performance gain between using a self built server that extends SimpleHTTPServer and Flask?

Comment: Are you having to meet strict performance reqs? If not then don't worry about it, very likely Flask will equal or outperform yours, not to mention the time you save on dev and maintenance. Or you just wonder if Flask will perform acceptably? Youd have to say what load you are targeting to support, but Flask is multithreaded, it's pretty solid AFAIK (but I have never run or seen benchmarks). Beyond that it is not possible to say without look at your code and making measurements to compare, clearly beyond scope.

Comment: My performance reqs are pretty minimal...basically just get it working so that it doesn't take minutes to load an html table that has a number of html textareas on the order of hundred (it currently takes this long, but I think it's primarily due to using excel as my database).  The target number of users at this point is probably around 10-20 so there isn't a lot of expected traffic.  Right now I have only extended SimpleHTTPServer via implementation of a POST handler that does minimal work.  I have noticed that SimpleHTTPServer drops a request for the POSTs 10% or more of the time...

Comment: Though in my POST handler I call a separate python script to handle the majority of the processing/database interfacing.  Would the server speed up if I just simply injected this separate python code directly into the file that the server lives in?

Comment: Oh also, the html textareas are being loaded by javascript/jquery.  So maybe SimpleHTTPServer is also slow handling these types of requests?